Can I have business outside Germany while on a Blue card
I've got an offer to move to Germany with a blue card, but I am considering an option to work for my current job as a part-time contractor(the contract will be outside EU IT)
I don't understand. Is it worth it? Will I have problems with the Tax authority, or it's even not legal?

Your Blue Card contains a line deciding whether it is legal, it reads either

Selbständige Tätigkeit/Nebentätigkeit gestattet.

or

Selbständige Tätigkeit/Nebentätigkeit nicht gestattet.

In theory, your full time employer has to agree to it. That said, both the authorities and the employer have to have solid reasons to disagree, they cannot just "not feel like it". If there is no reason for you not to work as a freelancer in the job you are obviously qualified for, they have to allow it. But still, you need to make it official, you need a line in your Blue Card that says it's allowed.
You would need to register with the tax authorities as a freelancer and your old employer would have to hire you as a contractor. Technically, sooner or later you will need another client, or you will need to have an actual company in your name, because having only a single client is considered being a fake "independent contractor", because obviously you are not independent with just one client. That however is a law to protect exploited workers from companies denying them labor rights as regular employees, the authorities have still plenty of exploited people to protect before they come for office workers making triple the average salary and their side hustle. Just say you are working on getting more clients.
On a personal, non-legal note: Moving to another country is not easy. It's stressful, everthing is new, paperwork for your Blue Card probably was a nightmare. Think hard about whether you want to add even more German paperwork on top. A side hustle can be exhausting after a full working day, and you are the new guy on probation, you need to be on your absolute best. You will need to fill out paperwork, get a tax accountant to make sure you get that whole mess right, find out how Germany works if you get sick or have problems with transportation or how to make sure your drivers license is valid over here. There are thousands of problems to solve, none of them huge, but all of them cost time. Time you want to sign away to work more.
Make sure you can do this. Have you ever worked freelance on the side in your old country? If you have and you think you can put even more on top of that, then yes maybe try it. If not, then maybe not pile on two totally new things. Pick one. Do it. Do it right, do it safe. And maybe start the side hustle at least after you are through probation of your first job.
